# XML error parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I've got the next XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partido>
    <datos_partido>
    </datos_partido>
    <estado_partido>
    </estado_partido>
    <marcador_parcial>
    </marcador_parcial>
    <listado_acciones>
    </listado_acciones>
</partido>
```

And I try to parsing that xml file in the constructor of a class using DOM:

```
public XMLManager(String pathXML) {
    try{
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(pathXML);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(file);
        setRoot(dom);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But, I've got the next error:

```
    Error: element stack empty (position:END_TAG </partido>@1:10 in 
    java.io.InputStreamReader@51e78c80)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This compiles and runs, and dom contains a correctly parsed DeferredDocumentImpl instance. What version of Java are you using? Are you using any extra parsing libraries? I did this on Darwin and Java 7.

Comment: Is this exception happening in builder.parse() or in setRoot(dom)? Are you doing additional work in setRoot that might be causing this?

Comment: Hi @Kylar!!!

The real XML is longer than the example, because stackoverflow doesn't let me write complete. But, If I use the real XML when I compiling and running like a java application, it works!!! However, If I use the same XML and runs and compiles in an Android application, then, I've got that error.

Comment: Hi @JenS!!!

No, I don't do anything extra in SetRoot. The code of SetRoot is:
`code`
        function void setRoot(root){
                this.root = root;
        }`code`

Comment: If you run an xml validator on the "real xml" does it show any errors? http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: Is it possible you have two end tags for </partido> ?

Comment: Hi @Kylar and @JenS!!!

I have validated the "real XML" and there is no errors. So, there is no two end tags for </partido>

Comment: Hi Kylar and JenS again!!! I don't know why but right now it works!!! I don't get any more that error. Thanks for your appreciated help!!!